# Limited to 100 mbps download with 20m cables

Tags: networking, ethernet

Looking for some advice as I'm having an extremely difficult time diagnosing what's going wrong with my wired internet connection. My internet download speed should be 1000 mbps and works as intended when using a 5 meter cable. However, when I connect with a 20m cable it reverts to 100 mbps. I have bought 4 different 20m cables from 2 manufacturers and the problem persists with all of them.

This is the text printed on the cables:

- 5m CAT 6E UTP 23AWG 4PR_ETL TIA_ETA_568B (**this one works at 1000mbps**)
- 20m CAT 6E UTP 23AWG 4PR_ETL TIA_ETA_568B (bought 2, both don't work. Same brand as 5m cable that works)
- 20m UTP CAT6E 4PAIRS ETA/TIA 568B (bought 2, both don't work)

I brought one of the cables back to the store where I purchased it and they showed me that the cable works at 1000mbps on their network, so the problem can't be the cable. Any advice is appreciated and I'd be glad to provide additional info if I missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect the socket on either end. Push the plu and test, pull and test etc.  Or buy or borrow an led tester for cat cables

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1204939/8672): "I posit that one of the wires is not punched down/crimped properly. Gigabit connectivity requires all 4 pairs work fine, while 100 megabit can run fine off 2 pairs."

Comment: What are cables connected to? Is it specific devices?  If the cables test fine at the store, I wonder if its something else

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the socket on either end. The pins may not be seated properly and perhaps don't make contact reliably.  All 4 pairs are required for 1Gb speed.  It could even be the cables themselves in that wires are not making contact properly.

- Push the plug in firmly and test,
- Pull the plug out(without unlocking or removing it) and test etc.
- Or buy or borrow an led tester for cat cables

> Like Cat 6, Cat 5e uses a four wire-pair signaling scheme to achieve its data throughput rates.

Quote from [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/cat6-ethernet-cable-standard-817553)

A Tester like this from Amazon is only $9.00.  I am not affiliated with Amazon.  The led lights up for each wire in turn and you can quickly see if a wire is not connected.  This will not test for intermittent connections, but I think it will work out for you.

[image: Tester]